# Adding registry key to run

Tags: c#, .net

i want to run my application on startup. for this purpose i found the following code ..

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
private void SetStartup()
{
        RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
            ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        if (chkStartUp.Checked)
            rk.SetValue(AppName, Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
        else
            rk.DeleteValue(AppName,false);     
}
```

my question is that where i apply this code in my application coding ?
please tell me step by step..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding the registry key via code, the ideal way would be to use an setup project and add your application in the Startup-folder. When you are creating the setup project, in the File System tab, right click on "File System on Target Machine", "Add Special Folder", "User's Startup Folder". Create a shortcut of your project output and drag that shortcut into the Startup folder.